# GitHub Action is failing: Automate release and pypi package version update

Tags: python-3.x, github, automation, yaml, github-actions

I want to Automate release and pypi package version update after using a patterned commit message like "Release v0.1.0" and add previous commits as release body. I have tried the below yml file but I am not getting the expected result.

```
name: Release

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - master

jobs:
    release:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v3
            - name: Set up Python
              uses: actions/setup-python@v1
              with:
                  python-version: 3.x
            - name: Install dependencies
              run: pip install -r requirements.txt
            - name: Get the current version
              id: current-version
              run: echo "::set-output name=version::$(python setup.py --version)"
            - name: Check if the commit message matches the release pattern
              run: |
                  if [[ $(git log -1 --pretty=%B) != "Release v${{ steps.current-version.outputs.version }}" ]]; then
                    echo "Commit message does not match the release pattern."
                    exit 1
            - name: Create a release
              run: |
                  python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
                  git tag -a "v${{ steps.current-version.outputs.version }}" -m "Release v${{ steps.current-version.outputs.version }}"
                  git push --follow-tags
            - name: Upload release to PyPI
              uses: pypa/gh-action-pypi-publish@v1.8.6
              with:
                  user: ${{ secrets.PYPI_USERNAME }}
                  password: ${{ secrets.PYPI_PASSWORD }}
```

Action is triggering but I am getting many errors in the middle
[image: Error Messages]

What is the problem in my yml code? Can any kind soul help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Missing `fi` for `if`.

Comment: Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to lint your shell scripts to quickly find bugs.

Comment: Apart from that, `set-output` is deprecated. See [Setting an output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) for new method with `GITHUB_OUTPUT`.